# Ruby: is comparing `GC.stat` allocation delta to RSS a valid method to prove a memory leak in garbage collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I have a memory leak in a Rails API, there's no doubt about it.

The first thing I want to know is whether the leak is related to garbage collection or not. If that's not the case, I'd have to go deeper and search for the cause in C native extensions.

I've put my API under an stress test using [`siege`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/siege) and stored the ouput of [`GC.stat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/GC.html#method-c-stat) into an ELK stack. Then graphed what would be `GC.stat[:total_allocated_objects] - GC.stat[:total_freed_objects]` in the left side and RSS in the right side. This are the results:

[image]

The upward tendency in the RSS proves the leak, but the "allocation/freeing delta" does not show growth (the small valley matches a short time when the siege command failed and I got to restart it).

Should I take this as a proof that the leak is not due to garbage collection issues?

Or, putting this in a more general perspective, **is comparing `GC.stat[:total_allocated_objects] - GC.stat[:total_freed_objects]` to `RSS` a reliable method to determine whether is there a leak in garbage collection due to misuse of the language?**